# When and where was the word "backup" used in this form for the first time?

Tags: etymology, origin-unknown

What is the etymology of the word "backup" (in the meaning of "a file copy" in computing)? I can't find the origin and the first using of this word in this very meaning. Why is "backup" so called?

There are some sources like [this](https://www.etymonline.com/word/back%20up) which writes about the first using of "back up" in 1767 and [this](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/backup) which writes about the first using of "backup" in 1775 or 1952 ([this](https://www.etymonline.com/word/backup)). But there are no text examples.

Comment: Specific reference to computing is from 1965. https://www.etymonline.com/word/backup

Comment: In earlier times a file copy would be a carbon copy of a typewritten business letter, kept in a correspondence file so there was a record of what had been sent.

Comment: @KateBunting do you have more information about this?

Comment: Only that I'm old enough to remember pre-computer business practices! When all documents had to be produced on a typewriter, the typist would insert two sheets of paper with carbon paper between them. This was thin, strong paper coated on one side with a black substance, which was transferred to the second sheet of paper making a duplicate copy of the document. Even earlier, when business letters were handwritten, the clerk would have to copy out the letter into a book so that the firm had a record of it.

Comment: @JEL I mean "backup" origin. You write "I have text evidence of the use of 'back-up copy' in computing as early as 1957" — it's interesting for me.

Comment: does this have any relevance to the phrase "wooh back up there" meaning to go back a step to how it was before

Comment: I suspect that there is a military origin -- a "backup" is an array of riflemen behind the first rank (or perhaps swordsmen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributive use of the noun 'back-up' (also 'backup') in the sense of "stand-by, reserve" is attested as early as 1952 in [*OED*](http://oed.com/):

> Orig[inally] *U.S.*...Also *attrib[utive] spec[ifically]* in Computing, (the making of) a duplicate copy of a disc, file, etc., for use in case of loss or corruption of the original.
>
> 1952  *Wall St. Jrnl.* 5 June 18   Value of the stocks, including 'back-up' supplies being held in warehouses for order filling, will total about £1 million.

Use in computing, as noted in *OED*, is not attested there until 1964; in 1965, the preparation of backup files is implied by the use attested:

> 1964   *CIS Gloss. Automated Typesetting* (Composition Information Services) 3   A back-up computer may be located in the same plant or hundreds of miles away.
>   1965   *Proc. AFIPS Conf.* 27 193/1   The backup procedures must be prepared for contingencies ranging from a dropped bit on a magnetic tape to a fire.

However, 'back-up' is used attributively in computing, in the phrases "back-up copy" and "back-up file", at least as early as 1957 and 1962, respectively:

> When the tape has been written, a copy should be made to serve as a *back-up copy*. This tape will contain seven binary files.
>
> ["TURBO : a two-dimensional few-group depletion code for the IBM-704*, J.B. Callaghan et al., November 1957.](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015095066000;view=1up;seq=48)  Emphasis mine.
>
> Since the punched deck is always maintained up-to-date, it provides a *back-up file* for the descriptor card catalog.
>
> [*Electrical and electronic properties of materials information retrieval program, final report*, by H. Thayne Johnson et al., June 1962.](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015030436839;view=1up;seq=55) Emphasis mine.